# Converting String to date in Databricks SQL returns null

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with string column named Date which contains the values
(`dd-Mon-yy` format data and `yyyy-mm-dd` format data )

```
01-jan-21
01-feb-21
01-mar-21
2021-01-01
2021-02-01
```

I was trying to convert it into a date format of `yyyy-mm-dd` for all the members

`to_date(date,'yyyy-mm-dd')` but it returns null .

How to convert a string to specific date format as `yyyy-mm-dd` in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have two different date types, you need to specify them separately:

```
select coalesce(to_date(date,'yyyy-MM-dd'), to_date(date,'dd-MMM-yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the format of the column.  In this case, you can just use the length:

```
(case when length(date) = 10 then to_date(upper(date), 'yyyy-MMM-dd')
      else to_date(date, 'yyyy-mon-dd')
 end)
```

Comment: This is making all the date with yyyy-mm-dd format to 2020-01-01

Comment: Also, 01-jan-2021 is still outputting as NULL.Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Our own date formater in spark SQL

```
Select date.split('-')[2]||'-'||case when length(date.split('-')[0]) = 1 then '0'||date.split('-')[0] else  date.split('-')[0] end  || case when length(date.split('-')[1]) = 1 then '0'||date.split('-')[1] else  date.split('-')[1] end] 
Date = date_column
```

Date format `yyyy-mm-dd`
Delimiter can be different.

Without any date format.